# How to make more concise (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

```
$("li.category-top >ul").hide();

    $(".category-top").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").show();
    });
   $(".category-top").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Definitely take Mu's solution below.  `hover()` combines `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.  (`mouseenter` always seems to work so much better than `mouseover` too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
$("li.category-top >ul").hide();
$('.category-top').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
});
```

Demo of the technique: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aKvkb/

References:

- [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
- [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

If you put the ul's into your css as display:none then you can save the hide line and just have the hover() call